# Ag grid - Master/ detail - multi detail

Tags: ag-grid

For Ag grid Master/Detail, is there a way to add more than one detail? In the eg. it only eg with one detail only.

Comment: Extend your question pls

Comment: @K. Santos Have you achieved that functionality?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are asking how to have a single master with multiple detail grids.

You will need to create your own [detailCellRender class/object](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#cell-renderer-component).
In the template definition for your class, you create as many detail grids as you need.
In the init method, you initialize the grid(s) and set their data.

It is very important to remember the [life-cycle of a cell renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#cell-renderer-component-lifecycle)!
The grid only exists while it is visible.

```
class MultipleDetailCellRenderer {
    constructor() {
        this.eGui = document.createElement("div");
    }

    init(params) {
    this.rowId = params.node.id;
    this.masterGridApi = params.api;
    // Note: assume data has an id field,
    // whatever you have defined in your column def should be available
    this.id=params.data.id;

    /* Build the div for the grid 1 */
    var grid_01 = document.createElement("div");
    grid_01.id = `grid01_${this.id}`;
    grid_01.classList = "ag-details-row-grid01";
    this.eGui.appendChild(grid_01);
    this.grid_01 = grid_01;
    
    /* Build the div for grid 2 */
    var grid_02 = document.createElement("div");
    grid_02.id = `grid02_${this.id}`;
    grid_02.classList = "ag-details-row-grid02";
    this.eGui.appendChild(grid_02);
    this.grid_02 = grid_02;

    // Theoretically, you can have more detail grids here too,
    // just go through the exercise of wiring them in
    
    if (this.grid_01 !== undefined && this.grid_02 !== undefined) {
        this.createDetailsGrids(params);
        this.registerDetailsWithMaster(params.node);
        this.loadRowData(params);
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.grid_01Options.api) {
                this.grid_01Options.api.doLayout();
            }
            if (this.grid_02Options.api) {
                this.grid_02Options.api.doLayout();
            }
        }, 0);
    }
}

getGui() {
    return this.eGui;
}

refresh(params) {
    return false;
}

destroy(params) {}

buildGridOptions() {
    var grid_01Options = {};
    grid_01Options.columnDefs = {}; // your column defs, required
    grid_01Options.getContextMenuItems = {}; // your context menu items, not required
    grid_01Options.popupParent = document.querySelector("#DivWhereMasterGridLives");
    // any event handlers for the detail grids go here
    grid_01Options.onCellDoubleClicked = params => {console.log("onCellDoubleClicked", params);};
    grid_01Options.onCellValueChanged = params => {console.log("onCellValueChanged", params);};
    // grid_01Options.rowClassRules = classRules; // css conditional row styling

    /* Config the 2nd detail grid */
    var grid_02Options = {};
    grid_02Options.columnDefs = {}; // your column defs, required
    grid_02Options.getContextMenuItems = {}; // your context menu items, not required
    grid_02Options.popupParent = document.querySelector("#DivWhereMasterGridLives");
    // any event handlers for the detail grids go here
    grid_02Options.onCellDoubleClicked = params => {console.log("onCellDoubleClicked", params);};
    grid_02Options.onCellValueChanged = params => {console.log("onCellValueChanged", params);};
    // grid_02Options.rowClassRules = classRules; // css conditional row styling

    this.grid_01Options = grid_01Options;
    this.grid_02Options = grid_02Options;
}

setRowData(grid01_data, grid02_data) {
    if (this.grid_01Options.api) {
        this.grid_01Options.api.setRowData(grid01_data);
    }
    if (this.grid_02Options.api) {
        this.grid_02Options.api.setRowData(grid02_data);
    }
}

loadRowData(params) {
    var grid01_data = []; // work your magic to get the data for grid 1
    var grid02_data = []; // work your magic to get the data for grid 2
    this.setRowData(grid01_data,grid02_data);
}

registerDetailsWithMaster(node) {
    var grid_01Info = {
        id: this.rowId,
        api: this.grid_01Options.api,
        columnApi: this.grid_01Options.columnApi
    };
    var grid_02Info = {
        id: this.rowId,
        api: this.grid_02Options.api,
        columnApi: this.grid_02Options.columnApi
    };
    this.masterGridApi.addDetailGridInfo(`grid01_${this.id}`, grid_01Info);
    this.masterGridApi.addDetailGridInfo(`grid02_${this.id}`, grid_02Info);
    this.addDestroyFunc = () => {
        this.masterGridApi.removeDetailGridInfo(`grid01_${this.id}`);
        this.masterGridApi.removeDetailGridInfo(`grid02_${this.id}`);
        node.addDetailGridInfo = null;
    };
}

createDetailsGrids(params) {
    this.buildGridOptions();
    new agGrid.Grid(this.grid_01, this.grid_01Options, {
        $scope: params.$scope,
        $compile: params.$compile
    });
    new agGrid.Grid(this.grid_02, this.grid_02Options, {
        $scope: params.$scope,
        $compile: params.$compile
    });
    this.grid_01Options.api.setDomLayout("autoHeight");
    this.grid_02Options.api.setDomLayout("autoHeight");

    this.addDestroyFunc = () => {
        if(this.grid_01Options.api) {
            this.grid_01Options.api.destroy();
        }
        if(this.grid_02Options.api) {
            this.grid_02Options.api.destroy();
        }
    };
}
```

}

Then in your master grid definition

```
    $scope.masterGridOpts.masterDetail = true;
    $scope.masterGridOpts.detailCellRenderer = MultipleDetailCellRenderer;
    $scope.masterGridOpts.detailCellRendererParams = {};
```

Comment: Have you seen any examples of multiple detail grids in the wild?  This would be most appreciated.

Comment: I never did find an example for multiple detail rows, so I have sanitized my implementation and shared a little bit of it.  In theory, you could have more than 2 detail grids for each master.  This is functional in AngularJS, but you may need to adapt for other versions/libraries.  Note that the detail grids only exist when the master is expanded and the detail grids are on the screen.  That caused me a lot of grief initially.  Hope this is helpful!

Comment: FYI, I found an angular version in their documentation examples..... https://plnkr.co/edit/4fBywHfsbe6jGQmz?preview

Answer (score 0):

According to agGrid's own website, this *is* now supported:

https://blog.ag-grid.com/introducing-version-20-of-ag-grid/

[image]

I've learned not to trust agGrid's documentation, until I see a working example.

Has anyone seen an example of this yet, or managed to get this working ?