# Multiple detail grids for one master grid in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

In ag-grid documentation, all the master / detail examples show only one detail grid implementation. Is there a way to add multiple (different) detail grids in one master grid (one row).

Comment: In order to achieve the goal you will probably need to create a custom `cellRenderer` with the grids you want to display inside. Here is related problem [Ag grid - Master/ detail - multi detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986626/ag-grid-master-detail-multi-detail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a *lot* of swearing and head-scratching, I did find a solution.

Have a look at the following video, in the section at 12m:50s "Nesting Master Detail", which shows how to do this using agGrid v20 onwards.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OeJn75or2w&t=770s

You simply need to embed a `detailCellRendererParams` within another `detailCellRendererParams`.

[image]