# How to display complex data structures in ag-grid Angular

Tags: angular, data-structures, datatable, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to display my data in ag-grid but I'm not sure how to create my grid. Can I group my actors? Or can I just group the films or awards? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 "rows": [
      {
        "actorId": "22",
        "firstName": "Gwyneth",
        "lastName": "Paltrow",
        "films": [
          {
            "name": "Iron Man"
          },
          {
            "name": "Avengers: Infinity War"
          }
        ],
        "awards": [
          {
            "name": "Oscar", 
            "year": "1999"
          },
          {
            "name": "Golden Globe Award",
            "year": "1999"
          }
        ]
      },...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [master-detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/master-detail/) (Enterprise feature).

If so, set your `columnDefs` like so:

```
  columnDefs = [
    { field: 'actorId', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' },
    { field: 'firstName' },
    { field: 'lastName' },
  ];
```

Create your `detailCellRendererParams`:

```
  detailCellRendererParams: any = {
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [{ field: 'name' }, { field: 'year' }],
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    },
    getDetailRowData: function (params) {
      // change this to params.successCallback(params.data.films); instead to see the films in the detail
      params.successCallback(params.data.awards);
    },
  };
```

And pass this to your grid in the html while also enabling master detail:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [modules]="modules"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    [detailCellRendererParams]="detailCellRendererParams"
    [masterDetail]="true"
    >

</ag-grid-angular>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-t3vzbw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thanks that's a good approach! But what if I want so display `films` and `awards` at once?

Comment: please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986626/ag-grid-master-detail-multi-detail) SOF question